# Generate SSH keys for Windows server acting as client

Tags: ssh, sftp, windows-server-2012-r2, ssh-keys

I have an app, which will be run by AutoSys on Windows 2012 server. The app should send csv via SFTP to Linux server. Under which account should I generate SSH keys on the Win12 server?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Which account is AutoSys using to run the app? Which account is being granted access to the CSV files?

Comment: It does not matter under which account you generate the keys. It's just a file. Though if you will be using OpenSSH tools (`ssh`/`sftp`/`scp`), they require that only the local account that runs the tool has permissions to the key file.